# How would you write a test for this method using Mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

Please assist in this. I can't seem to create a suitable test for this method:

```
protected void startInterfacing() {

    mLiveAuthClient.login(mView.context(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES), new LiveAuthListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthComplete(final LiveStatus liveStatus, final LiveConnectSession liveConnectSession,
                                   Object o) {

            // Login successful and user consented, now retrieve user ID and connect with backend server
            getUserIdAndConnectWithBackendServer(liveConnectSession, mLiveAuthClient);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException e, Object o) {
            // We failed to authenticate with auth service... show error
            if (e.getError().equals("access_denied") ||
                    e.getMessage().equals("The user cancelled the login operation.")) {

                // When user cancels in either the login or consent page, we need to log the user out to enable
                // the login screen again when trying to connect later on
                logUserOut(mLiveAuthClient, false);
            } else {
                onErrorOccured();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'll explain abit what goes on here:
I'm trying to authenticate my client and log into OneDrive.
The method starts with a call to the Live SDK's login method. That SDK object is given to me from outside this class. So I can basically mock it.
Here's what I'm struggling with:

1. I do not need to test the call to the login method because it is not mine. I do need to test the call to  getUserIdAndConnectWithBackendServer() inside onAuthComplete. But this method requires a liveConnectSession object. How do I provide that? It is given to me on the onAuthComplete method.
2. How do I mock the calls to onAuthComplete and onAuthError? I read about ArgumentCaptor but when I use that, I need to provide the arguments to those methods when I call the actual method.
   For instance, argument.getValue().onAuthComplete() requires me to add arguments to this call. What do I actually provide here?

Here is the next method which is roughly the same but has its own issues:

```
 protected void getUserIdAndConnectWithBackendServer(final LiveConnectSession liveConnectSession, final LiveAuthClient
        authClient) {

    final LiveConnectClient connectClient =  new LiveConnectClient(liveConnectSession);

    connectClient.getAsync("me", new LiveOperationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(LiveOperation liveOperation) {

            // We got a result. Check for errors...
            JSONObject result = liveOperation.getResult();
            if (result.has(ERROR)) {
                JSONObject error = result.optJSONObject(ERROR);
                String code = error.optString(CODE);
                String message = error.optString(MESSAGE);
                onErrorOccured();
            } else {
                connectWithBackend(result, liveConnectSession, authClient);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(LiveOperationException e, LiveOperation liveOperation) {
            // We failed to retrieve user information.... show error
            onErrorOccured();
            logUserOut(authClient, false);
        }
    });
}
```

In here I would like to mock the JSONObject for instance. But how do I call the onComplete method, or the onError method. And what would I provide as the arguments the methods provide me with. LiveOperation for instance?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually used was to use mockito's doAnswer() structure.
This enabled me to get the callback argument and call one of its methods.
Another solution was to use an ArgumentCator.